# How to fix Bash script errors

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a little Bash script called cs210_list.sh, and it is giving me the following errors when i run it either as bash cs210_list.sh or as
sh cs210_list.sh in linux:

cs210_list.sh: line 2: [0: command not found

cs210_list.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

cs210_list.sh: line 21: `       fi'

this is my very first bash script ever. I can't figure why I'm getting the errors. BTW, "(line 21)" is not actually in my code, it's just there for your reference.

$? -eq 0  This command is supposed to determine if there as a argument

```
#!/bin/bash
if [$? -eq 0];
then
   echo "Error: Missing argument";
   exit 1
fi
if [-e "$1"];
then
    if [-d "$1"];
    then
        for i in $(ls)
        do
            if [-d "$i"];
            then
                echo "File: $i"
                echo ""
            else
                echo "File: $i"
                echo "  Size: " $(stat -c%s $i)
            fi
     fi (line 21)
else
    echo "$Error: File doesn't exist"
fi  
done
```

Comment: You need a space after the `[`

Comment: A good place to start when you run into issues with your shell script is [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Just paste your script in and it will spit out the issues.

Comment: I think `$?` is not what you intended, you need `$#` to get the number of CLI arguments, while `$?` returns the exit code (0 if the last command succedded)

Comment: `[` is not a metacharacter in bash. Therefore bash treats the token `[$?` as one token. Then, it does parameter expansion of `$?`, which gets replaced by `0`. Therefore your final word becomes `[0`, which it tries to find in `$PATH`, and doesn't. If you put a space between `[` and `$?`, then the space, being a metacharacter, would separate the 2 and it would represent what you intended to.

Comment: As an aside (regarding the line `fi (line 21)`), note that in Bash, comments can be added by prepending the `#` character. E.g.: `fi  # line 21`

Comment: To emphasize euphoria83's comment,  `[` is actually a **command**, and like any other command, you need whitespace to separate the command from the arguments. At a bash prompt type `help [` then `help test`